# Exclude records from one table based on count in joined table

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I have two tables: Coupons and Responses.

The Coupons table includes fields such as:

- VendorID [key]
- CouponID [key]
- CouponDescription

The Responses table includes fields such as:

- RespondentID [key]
- CouponID [key]
- (VendorID not repeated in this table.)
- Accepted [true/false]
- Rejected [true/false]
- Rating [1 to 5]

When someone accepts a coupon, they eventually rate it in the Responses table. Likewise, when someone rejects a coupon, the rejection appears in the Responses table.

When fetching a list of available coupons from the Coupons table, I'd like to exclude vendors who previously received two or more rejections from a respondent. For instance if RespondentID 3 previously rejected two or more coupons from Vendor 47, all coupons from Vendor 47 would no longer be shown to RespondentID 3.

Two things make it difficult for a SQL novice like myself.

1. The first is how to write the subquery that counts rejections *from* a particular vendor and *by* a particular respondent.
2. The second is how to join-back (so to speak) the Responses table to the Coupons table so that the sub-query of the Responses table bases its result on the RespondentID (which is in the Responses table) and the VendorID (which is *not* in the Responses table and must be determined based on the CouponID (which is in both tables).

Thanks for your assistance. It's always appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the information you want? You say "a list of available coupons from the Coupons table". Do you mean coupons you want to show to a particular respondent (here with RespondentID = 3)?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Yes, exactly what you're saying. Respondent 3 logs on to see which coupons are available, and only sees those from vendors he has not previously rejected two or more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with...

```
SELECT
   * 
   FROM Coupons C 
   WHERE C.OriginatorID NOT IN (
      SELECT 
         DISTINCT C.OriginatorID 
         FROM Responses R  
         INNER JOIN Coupons C ON C.CouponID = R.CouponID 
         WHERE C.OriginatorID IN  (
            SELECT Originators FROM (
               SELECT C.OriginatorID As Originators, Sum(R.Rejected) AS Rejections 
               FROM Responses R INNER JOIN Coupons C ON C.CouponID = R.CouponID
               WHERE R.RespondentID = 1
               GROUP BY C.OriginatorID
            ) AS RejectionTally 
            WHERE Rejections > 1
         )
   )
```

It has the disadvantage of an additional embedded SELECT, but it appears that most of the performance hit occurs the moment I attempt to exclude particular OriginatorIDs from the Coupons table anyhow. For example, manually entering an exclusion, such as...

```
SELECT * FROM Coupons WHERE OriginatorID <> 10
```

has the same effect. On a test table of 50 rows, the processing time is .27s as opposed to an unconstrained query that has a processing time of .08s.

The extra embedding is due to my needing a single column for the outer NOT IN (i.e., the OriginatorID's that I'm seeking to exclude). That meant I had to first create the SUMs, then isolate the records whose SUM was less than the criterion (1), and then exclude those records.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like this:

```
   SELECT * FROM Coupons 
     WHERE VendorId NOT IN (
        SELECT C.VendorId 
          FROM Responses R JOIN Coupons C ON R.CouponId = C.CouponId
          WHERE R.RespondentID = 3 AND R.Rejected = True
          GROUP BY C.VendorId
          HAVING SUM(R.Rejected) > 2
     )
```

I've never used `HAVING` without including the value it in the `SELECT` but I think it could work. Also, not sure about the data type of Rejected, probably SUM() won't work.

Comment: Thanks, Carlos. Would this result in a vendor being excluded even if there was only a single rejection? If so, it needs to be only the vendors that a particular user has rejected two or more times.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's the end of my broadcast day here, so I'll give it a try first thing tomorrow morning. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Carlos. Your code worked if I didn't include a RespondentID. As soon as I did, all records were returned.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a long shot and I'm not sure this query will actually run, but I think the key is that you have to include the Coupon table twice. Try this (I think, however, that `where` is not allowed like this):

```
select c.CouponID, c.CouponDescription,
       (select count(r.CouponID)
          from Responses r
         inner join Coupons c2 on c2.CouponID = r.CouponID
         where r.RespondentID = 3
           and r.Rejected = true
           and c2.VendorID = c.VendorID) as countRejections

  from Coupons c
 where countRejections < 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I appreciate it. I'll try both solutions, yours and Carlos', tomorrow and will report back.

Comment: Hi Tom. Unfortunately, I got a syntax error when trying your solution. The error message wasn't specific enough for me to track down the problem.